# Dereference of a possibly null reference ... Can my code be simplified?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

My project is .Net-6 Blazor WebAssembly (hosted) in C#. Can my code be simplified to avoid nullable warnings?
I want the person's customer-ID in a page variable from the ApplicationUser object's Identity Name (variable is '_Name').  Thanks.

```
List<Person> listPersons = (List<Person>)(await PService.GetPersons()).ToList();
Person oPerson = new Person();
if (listPersons != null){
    oPerson = (Person)listPersons.Where(p => p.Name!.Equals(_Name)).FirstOrDefault();
}
if (oPerson != null) {
    _UID_CUSTOMER = oPerson.UID_CUSTOMER;
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong with that code. `listPersons.Where(...)` will return an `IEnumerable<Person>` which you CANNOT cast to `(Person)`.

Comment: `Where` filters `listPersons`, giving you an `IEnumerable<Person>` not a `Person`. It seems you want `.FirstOrDefault` or perhaps `.SingleOrDefault` instead of `.Where`

Comment: By not having a `?` in the data type for `listPersons` (such as `List<Person>?`) you're saying that `listPersons` can never be null. What is the return type (and specifically the nullability of that return type) of `PService.GetPersons()`?

Comment: I fixed the code error pointed out by the first two replies.  @gunr2171 question...It returns an IEnumerable<Person> (list of all person-objects and is not empty of persons).  Hope this helps.  thanks.

Comment: So then why are you doing a null check at all? If your first method call returns `IEnumerable<Person>`, that means it can't be null. In fact, even if it _was_ null, `.ToList()` would throw an exception before the if statement even runs. How much do you know about the [nullable reference types feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) in c#?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and question -- I know a little that the .Net-6 compiler anticipates when a variable can be null and shows a warning in the code with green-squiggly line.  The code above was my attempt to eliminate the NRT warnings by coding "if !=null".  It appears to me that we coders now have to think about each variable to determine if null is possible.  Is that true?  Should I simply code to reduce the number of If...null  statements since NONE of the objects or fields could be null, except for the Person.Name field which contains "Name!".

Comment: What's the data type of `Name`? `string` or `string?`? Do you allow `Name` to hold a null value?

Comment: It is declared as string?  in the Person-model and nullable in the SQL-DB.  I am in development and previously was not sure of some of the persons names that were added "by hand" from an excel import into the DB.  However, since that original period, every Person-object now has a Name value.  Perhaps I should change the model and the DB-table now.  The adding of a person is now coded in the app and thus future programmatically entered person will always have a Name-field not null.  You are outstandingly smart! I have seen some of your posts.  I wished you lived in New Port Richey FL. LOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you work with the [Nullable Reference Type feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), you need to consider, *for every (reference) variable*, whether that variable allows a null.

This is no different than value types, such as `int`. You wouldn't do

```
int a = 5;
if (a != null) { /* ... */ }
```

because `a` can never be null. You'd need to use the `int?` datatype to even *allow*  `a` to be null.

Granted, there are way to break the Nullable Reference Type feature - such as ignoring warnings.

---

Let's take your code and fix some problems. I'll add line numbers.

```
1  List<Person> listPersons = (List<Person>)(await PService.GetPersons()).ToList();
2  Person oPerson = new Person();
3  if (listPersons != null){
4      oPerson = (Person)listPersons.Where(p => p.Name!.Equals(_Name)).FirstOrDefault();
5  }
6  if (oPerson != null) {
7      _UID_CUSTOMER = oPerson.UID_CUSTOMER;
8  }
```

#### Line 1

`await PService.GetPersons()` returns an `IEnumerable<Person>`. Because there's no `?`, that means that the whole object cannot be null. In addition, each element (each Person object within the stream) cannot be null. If you really expect `PService.GetPersons()` to give you data *or* null, the return type would be `Task<IEnumerable<Person>?>`.

The cast of the `IEnumerable<Person>` into a `List<Person>` is dangerous. You get an `IEnumerable<Person>`, an interface. The underlying collection *could* be a List, or it could be an Array, or something else that implements `IEnumerable`. Casting it to a List can lead to runtime errors when the implementation of `PService.GetPersons()` changes.

There's not much point of running `ToList()` *after* the cast to a List. It's already a list. In fact, assuming you didn't get a cast exception, this method would throw an exception if the List was null. This eliminates the point of doing a null check at all.

So, here's a better Line 1:

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = await PSService.GetPersons();
```

- Use the right plural for "person".
- Keep the type `IEnumerable<Person>`, no need to cast to List if you're only going to use the stream once.

#### Line 2

You set the default of `oPerson` to a new instance of a Person, and the datatype (`Person`) says that it can never hold a null value. However, on line 4, you use `FirstOrDefault`, which the "Default" will be null. So we need to change the datatype to account for that.

In addition, we're going to rewrite line 4 so that line 4 always runs, and the initialization of the variable on line 2 is unnecessary.

In fact, this whole line is unneeded, because it would just be the varaible name. So remove it.

#### Line 3 and Line 5

There's no point in checking the nullability of `listPersons` (now called `people`), because you've told the compiler that it can't be null. Remove those lines.

#### Line 4

Inside the Where you have `Name!.Equals()`. The `!` is the "null forgiveness" operator. Problem with that is that if `Name` *is null*, then `.Equals()` will throw an exception. Replace `.Equals` with `==`. (This is all assuming that the datatype of `Name` is a `string?`).

The cast at the end is also unnecessary. `FirstOrDefault` will return a `Person` (actually a `Person?`), so casting it to the same data type is wasteful.

```
Person? oPerson = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == _Name);
```

Side note, I don't agree with making the "default" value from `FirstOrDefault` a new instance of Person. My opinion is that `FirstOrDefault`'s default should be null. This to me makes semantic sense for your code. You're looking through a list to find a matching person. If you can't find one, then you get null, not some new empty person.

#### Lines 6, 7, and 8

These are fine.

However, you could simplify the lines if the value of `_UID_CUSTOMER` was already null before executing these lines. In that case, all the lines could be replaced with:

```
_UID_CUSTOMER = oPerson?.UID_CUSTOMER;
```

This means:

- If oPerson is null, just use null
- If oPerson is not null, use the value of UID_CUSTOMER

Again, this only works if you didn't care about the value of `_UID_CUSTOMER` before this line executes. If you want to overwrite `_UID_CUSTOMER` ***only*** when `oPerson` is not null, change it back to the if statement.

---

So, putting it all together you get

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = await PSService.GetPersons();
Person? oPerson = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == _Name);
_UID_CUSTOMER = oPerson?.UID_CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation! Crystal clear to me.  In the time from 3-hours ago, I reformed my code to something very similar to yours AND I changed the DB and the Model to non-nullable values for the fields of interest discussed below.  I shall copy your code to replace my code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid nullable warning by removing this setting from csproj file

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

And have these settings

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>    
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```